# How to create hyperlink using Apache POI and Java?

Tags: java, excel, selenium, hyperlink, apache-poi

I wanted to create a hyperlink using Apache POI and Java for Selenium Webdriver automation testing. But the thing is, when i'm creating a hyperlink using this code :

```
File file=((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
String screenshotLocation = "D:\\MyFolder\\Test Results\\Screenshots\\";
screenshotURL=screenshotLocation+datetimestamp+".png";
FileUtils.copyFile(file, new File(screenshotURL));
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
HSSFHyperlink link = (HSSFHyperlink)createHelper.createHyperlink(Hyperlink.LINK_FILE);
link.setAddress(screenshotURL);
hyperlinkList.add(link); // add all hyperlinks to an arraylist
```

`createHyperlink` and `LINK_FILE` are showing as `deprecated`. Is there any alternate way to create hyperlink without deprecation? ( I've tried with XSSF also, but getting the same deprecation.)

FYI: when i'm using *selenium-server-standalone-2.47.1.jar* and *poi-bin-3.17-beta1-20170701* , it is showing only the deprecation, not any error. But when i'm using updated version, for example *Selenium-java-2.48.2.jar* and *poi-bin-3.17-20170915*, along with the deprecation, one error message is showing: **LINK_FILE cannot be resolved or is not a field.**

Please Help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Hyperlink.LINK_FILE` is replaced by  `HyperlinkType.FILE`
and the createHyperlink function was replaced by a new Funtion with the Parameter if type `HyperlinkType`

From the javadoc:

> Hyperlink createHyperlink(int type)
>
> Deprecated. POI 3.15 beta 3. Use createHyperlink(HyperlinkType)
>   instead.

And

> static int LINK_FILE 
>   Deprecated.   POI 3.15 beta 3. Use HyperlinkType.FILE instead.